Как написать приложение диагностики?
Есть вот такой сайт https://help.kontur.ru/ на котором скачивается утилитка и проверяется компьютер. Как написать что-то подобное? В какую сторону копать? Не совсем понятна связь веб морды и самой утилиты

Контур и Сбис приложения диагностики используют свои приложения, установленные на компьютер. Отображают данные, полученные этими приложениями.
Связь сайта и приложения может организовываться 2-мя способами:

У Сбис запускается веб+вэбсокет сервер и сайт  общается с компом по http.

У Контура есть расширение в браузере, сайт общается с расширением сигналами, а расширение общается с программой на компе через native-messaging.


